# NHibernate, mapping an association to same table

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, nhibernate, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I've an entity *A* which has an *Id* and *ParentId* column.

Currently I'm mapping it using a many-to-one relationship `<many-to-one name="Parent" column="ParentID" />`.

*Parent* property is of type *A*. In other words, *Parent* is an object of *A*.

Basically the problem is property "Parent" is always *null*, but this is incorrect since database has *ParentID* assigned with the right identifier.

What's wrong?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

I got a hint. In fact, I've another entity which maps many instances of *A*.

If I get the other entity which has a collection of *A*, *A* entities have its *Parent* property unloaded. In the other hand, if I get an *A* by its *Id*, *Parent* gets loaded as expected.

It's something with the other mapping then:

```
<set name="Fields" table="A" cascade="all-delete-orphan" lazy="false">
  <key column="AID" />

  <one-to-many
    class="A"
  />
</set>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That should work. Make sure you have an foreign-key constraint on ParentId to Id, and you can try adding class="A, Assembly" to your many-to-one mapping to be explicit.

Comment: Hey, thanks. It has FK in the database, I've tried _class_ attribute giving the full qualified assembly name of the mapped type, and it's still null.

Comment: That's weird. Can you look at the NH debug log and see what sql is being generated? That will probably help determine what NH is misinterpreting.

Comment: It was another thing unrelated to NHibernate. Thank you anyway.